# Custom Decorators with Graphql decorator

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs, typescript-decorator

I was making my own decorator to log input parameters and output result for each method.
By the way, if I use the decorator with `@Mutation` decorator. It occurs error according to the order of use.

My decorator looks like:

```js
export const Log = (): MethodDecorator => (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value

  descriptor.value = async function (...args) {
    console.log(args); // Write input log
    const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    console.log(result); // Write output log
    return result;
  }

  return descriptor;
}
```

Usage:

```js
@Mutation(() => Question, { name: 'question' })
@Log()
async question(@Args('input') input: QuestionInput): Promise<Question> {
  return await this.questionService.createOne({ ...input });
}
```

It doesn't occur error if I use decorators `@Mutation()` -> `@Log()` order. But `@Log()` -> `@Mutation()` order doesn't work.

What should I check first? Is there any other idea for logging the input and output of a method?

Comment: Any reason to not use an interceptor for something like this? Anytime you start modifying the `descriptor.value` things start getting a little wonky

Comment: I've tried using `interceptor`. But I couldn't get input params and return value through the interceptor. I have to look into it more. Do you have any idea to get input param and return value with interceptor? @JayMcDoniel

Comment: [This interceptor and its parsers](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/main/packages/nestjs-module/src/interceptor/ogma.interceptor.ts) manage recording a lot of metadata about requests. It might be helpful for you to look at